# Fetch Huge data from server using Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-volley, android-webservice

I have an Android app that fetches huge amount of data from a Mysql server, i'm using php to fetch data.

Using Volley library for network request.

Suppose of i have 100 names
I want my app to load data in modules like 10 at a time. once 10 names are loaded i need to send a request again to fetch the next 10 i.e from 11-20 and so on.

Cant find a solution anywhere.

StackOverflow u guys are my last Hope.

[I need something this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRV8i.png)

Comment: follow this: get count of total records, form that count get pages, and then pass page number in query. use `LIMIT` in mysql.

Comment: thanx for the reply, can u give me a code sinppet of how to using volley

Comment: 100 names = huge data?

Comment: sure.. let me provide demo..

Comment: @Andreas  100 for an example

Answer (score 0):

Try this demo:

Suppose, total records are 100, so count would be 100 and page will be 100/10 = 10. So first time call $page = 1. So first 10 records will be in response. second time $page = 2, so from 11-20 records will be there.. page count is from application side.

```
<?php
function test($page)
{
    if($page == '') {
        $page = 1;
    }
    if($page == 1)
    {
        $start = 0;
        $end = 10;
    }
    else
    {
        $start = ($page-1)*10;
        $end = 10;
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name LIMIT $start,$end";
    // further process with data.
}
?>
```

Comment: hope this is helpful and understandable.

Comment: Thanx for the code i get the php part, but is it possible for you to give a snippet of java function using volley?

Comment: i don't have knowledge about this. i can only help you for php

Comment: but if you have basic knowledge then it is done with code provided

Comment: network calls  are async i.e if i call a volley function in a loop it runs asynchronously which shouldnt be happening. multiple calls will be made without even finishing the first call

Comment: call web-service according to required

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

```js
<?php
function test($start,$limit)
{
    
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name LIMIT $start,$limit";
    // further process with data.
}

for($i=0;$i<100;$i=$i+10){
test($i,10);
}
?>
```

Comment: i get the php part. i need to load data like how ecommerce app load data 10 products at a time